# Flyway Found Non-Empty schema using H2 and REST-ASSURED

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, flyway, rest-assured

I'm trying to run some tests using SpringBoot, Flyway and H2

My RestAssured test classes extends:

```
   @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
   @EnableConfigurationProperties
   public class FunctionalTest {
       @LocalServerPort
       private int port;
       public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:FREE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL";
       @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
       private String username;

       @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
       private String password;

       @Before
       public void setUp() {
           Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
           flyway.setDataSource(JDBC_URL, username, password);
           flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration");
           flyway.migrate();
           AppContext.loadApplicationContext(this.context);
           RestAssured.port = this.port;

           CreateEntityUtil.init(organizationRepositoryInj, projectRepositoryInj, apiServerRepositoryInj, userServiceInj, userOrgServiceInj);
       }
   }
```

application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:FREE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
    spring.datasource.username=[EDITED]
    spring.datasource.password=[EDITED]

    flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
    flyway.schemas=FREE
```

Some developers run the tests and everything is fine.
But others get the following error:
Flyway Found non-empty Schema

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, I solved the problem using:

- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#repair--
- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#clean

  ```
     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
         flyway.setDataSource(JDBC_URL, username, password);
         flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration");
         flyway.setSchemas(flywaySchemas);
         flyway.repair(); // Repairs the History Table
         flyway.clean(); // Drops all Objects
         flyway.migrate(); // Execute necessary migrations
         AppContext.loadApplicationContext(this.context);
         RestAssured.port = this.port;

         CreateEntityUtil.init(organizationRepositoryInj, 
         projectRepositoryInj, apiServerRepositoryInj, userServiceInj, 
         userOrgServiceInj);
      }
  ```